# Why can the target of the OUTPUT INTO clause not be a view?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Here is my statement:

DELETE FROM table1 
OUTPUT deleted.col1, deleted.col2 
INTO view1;

It gives me this error:

The target 'view1' of the OUTPUT INTO clause cannot be a view or common table expression.

The view is simple and updatable. Why can I not insert into an updatable view using the OUTPUT clause?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From MSDN - [Output clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx):

"The OUTPUT clause is not supported in the following statements:

- DML statements that reference local partitioned views, distributed partitioned views, or remote tables.
- INSERT statements that contain an EXECUTE statement.
- Full-text predicates are not allowed in the OUTPUT clause when the database compatibility level is set to 100.
- **The OUTPUT INTO clause cannot be used to insert into a view, or rowset function.**
- A user-defined function cannot be created if it contains an OUTPUT INTO clause that has a table as its target.
  "

Comment: Shame. I'm just wondering what reasons MS give for this restriction...

Comment: You should be able to fix this if you output in a table variable and then you will be able to use this data for your view.

Comment: It's not a major problem, I can do the same operation in two statements, but the advantage to the output clause is the speed because it's all done in one statement. Table variables are slow!

Comment: I think that MS were a little lazy as the view could be a view onto the table you are deleting from (a little recursive I know)...  Have you tried outputting to the underlying table?

Comment: OUTPUT INTO has some limitations, including the output to a table with foreign keys, which is not accepted, from what I recall. It's essentially a help when you want to have the last set of data that you've changed and have it in a temp table/table variable and ready to work it further. It's not exactly a statement that does it all in one :).